# Php - Looping For Different CSS

Tags: php, html, css, xhtml, loops

MySQL

```
$selectSize     = "SELECT * FROM products";
$querySize      = $db->select($selectSize);
while ($product = $db->fetcharray($querySize)) {
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Product A</li>
<li>Product B</li>
<li class='right'>Product C</li>
<li>Product D</li>
<li>Product E</li>
<li class='right'>Product F</li>
</ul>
```

Question

While getting the product, I want the Product C and Product F or any product after 3 loops will have class='right' to the list style. Let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like the following (your code snippet was a little short)

```
$index = 1;
while ($product = $db->fetcharray($querySize)) {
    if ($index % 3 == 0) {
        //add your class here
    }
    $index++;
    //...
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Fingland. You rock!

Answer (score 3):

.

```
$count = 0;
while ($product = $db->fetcharray($querySize)) {
    echo "<li" . ((++$count % 3) ? "" : " class=\"right\"") . ">" 
        . $product['name']
        . "</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($product as $key=>value){
echo "<li" . (!(!is_nan($key) && $key % 3) ? " class=\"right\"" : "") . ">"
. $product['name']
. "</li>\n"; 
}
```